# Repeatable random placement of items on a grid

Tags: algorithm

I hope this is the right forum for this kind of general question, please tell me if I should address this to another place.

I have a grid NxN on which I want to place 'randomically' M items, each of these items has a unique Id (integer).
Anytime I do this placement with the same set of items (same Ids) I want the same distribution for each item.

Basically I need to build a placement function that takes as input the array of Ids and gives as output an array of coordinates but I have no clue how to start.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hash your ids, use it as a seed for a PRNG, then run your random placement algorithm.

Comment: Most languages have built in pseudorandom generators (eg Python's `random` module). If your language does not, finding code for a Mersenne Twister is a good choice.

Comment: Do you have a language in mind?

Comment: @pjs Yes, thank you, I saw that but was inviting OP to suggest adding the languages he is familiar with.

Comment: @MarkSetchell When I see just the algorithm tag I assume OP is looking for pseudocode equivalence. I tend to think Ruby or Python are effectively pseudocode, except they actually run. I guess we'll find out when it's morningtime in Italy.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for the interest in my question, pjs gave the answer. I did not mention a programming language because I did not want to limit the possibility to receive an answer.

Comment: Excellent! It's a good answer and I'm glad it works for you - he already has my upvote Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to generate individual locations based on the individual ID values, you're likely to encounter collisions due to the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). You can deal with this using techniques developed for hash tables, but those get clunky and potentially expensive as M approaches N*N, so I've interpreted your question to mean that the same set of IDs will generate the same set of grid locations.

The solution presented below assumes that you have access to a PRNG which produces an identical stream of values when given the same seed value. The ID values (or their hashes if they're non-numeric) are pooled in a repeatable way to generate the seed. I went with XORing, which avoids possible overflow issues, but you can substitute your own favorite mapping from the ID set to a seed value. The PRNG is then used to shuffle a list of the integers from 0 to (N*N)-1, and the first M values are picked off. Those are mapped into 2-d coordinates using an old trick involving division to get the row index and modulus to get the column index. Since the M values are guaranteed to be unique, so are the corresponding grid indices. This assumes array indexing is zero-based, shift by adding 1 for languages which are one-based. It also assumes that you have access to a shuffle method. If not, it's quite easy to implement a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Without further ado, here's a heavily annotated implementation in Ruby:

```ruby
def grid_locs(ids, n)
  fail "More IDs than grid locations!" if ids.length > n*n
  # Generate a seed by XORing all of the ids with 0xFFFFFFFF
  id_based_seed = ids.inject(0xFFFFFFFF) { |memo, x| memo ^ x }
  # Use this to seed the built-in PRNG
  srand(id_based_seed)
  # Create an array containing the numbers 0 up to N*N - 1 
  unique_values = Array.new(n*n) { |i| i }
  # Shuffle the array, pick off the first M values, convert them
  # to 2-d indices using the ancient division & modulo trick, and
  # return the results as a set of M unique grid locations
  return unique_values.shuffle[0...ids.size].map do |index|
    [index / n, index % n]
  end
end

# Helper to print the 2-d grid
def print_2d(ary)
  ary.each { |row| p row }
  puts
end

# # I initially generated random IDs, but then stored them for reproducibility
# id = Array.new(5) { rand(1..0xFFFFFFFF) }
ids = [4146364446, 2782840243, 4137630311, 3993445117, 3133691672]

# Generate and print a grid of asterisks
two_d_table = Array.new(4) { |i| Array.new(4) { '*' } }
puts "Before:"
print_2d two_d_table

# Generate and print grid locations using the method above
locations = grid_locs(ids, two_d_table.size)
puts "Locations: #{locations.inspect}"
puts

# Place ID index at each of the generated locations and print the results
locations.each.with_index { |loc, i| two_d_table[loc[0]][loc[1]] = i }
puts "After:"
print_2d two_d_table
```

which produces:

```text
Before:
["*", "*", "*", "*"]
["*", "*", "*", "*"]
["*", "*", "*", "*"]
["*", "*", "*", "*"]

Locations: [[0, 2], [3, 2], [3, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1]]

After:
["*", "*", 0, "*"]
["*", "*", 3, "*"]
["*", 4, "*", "*"]
["*", 2, 1, "*"]
```

The locations are identical given the same set of indices, but will change based on different numbers of indices or different index values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've just translated this in C# and worked like a charm.
Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad that worked for you.  In line with the comments on the question, I don't know C# so I wouldn't have attempted an answer had you specified the language despite finding it an interesting question.